# svn2git migration error command failed: git checkout -f master

Tags: git, svn, svn2git

I have a project structure in following format. It is located at https://ip/svn/siguard/DSA/

- branches/
- docs/
- tags/
- trunk/

I have installed svn2 git and make all installations. I want to run migration process with following command

```
 svn2git https://ip/svn/siguard/ --trunk DSA/trunk --branches DSA/branches --branches DSA/docs --tags DSA/tags --authors author.txt --verbose
```

and this is output.

```
Running command: git svn init **--prefix=svn/** --no-metadata --trunk='DSA/trunk' --tags='DSA/tags' --branches='DSA/branches' --branches='DSA/docs' https://141.29.113.138/svn/siguard/
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/GitMigration/DSA/.git/
Running command: git config --local --get user.name
Running command: git config --local svn.authorsfile authors.txt
Running command: git svn fetch
W: Ignoring error from SVN, path probably does not exist: (160013): Filesystem has no item: '/svn/siguard/!svn/bc/100' path not found: Additional errors:: File not found: revision 100, path '/'DSA'
W: Do not be alarmed at the above message git-svn is just searching aggressively for old history.
This may take a while on large repositories
Checked through r100
Checked through r200
Checked through r300
Checked through r400
Checked through r500
Checked through r600
Checked through r700
Checked through r800
Checked through r900
Checked through r1000
Checked through r1100
Checked through r1200
Checked through r1300
Checked through r1400
Checked through r1500
Checked through r1600
Checked through r1700
Checked through r1800
Checked through r1900
Checked through r2000
Checked through r2100
Checked through r2200
Checked through r2300
Checked through r2400
Checked through r2500
Checked through r2600
 Checked through r2700
Checked through r2800
Checked through r2900
Checked through r3000
Checked through r3100
Checked through r3200
Checked through r3300
Checked through r3400
Checked through r3500
Checked through r3600
Checked through r3700
Checked through r3800
Checked through r3900
Checked through r4000
Checked through r4017
Running command: git branch -l --no-color
Running command: git branch -r --no-color
Running command: git config --local --get user.name
Running command: git config --local --get user.email
Running command: git checkout -f master
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
command failed:
git checkout -f master
```

I do not know what is problem. When I google svn2git it seems everything is ok with this utility.

Answer (score 1):

There are pleny tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

The `svn2git` you used is based on `git-svn` and `git-svn` is **not** the right tool for one-time conversions of repositories or repository parts. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though git-svn (or the wrong svn2git in your case) is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

There are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your support. Now I migrated using git-svn